# document.getElementsById("").innerHTML does not change the p tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, for-loop

HTML

```
{% load static %}

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'lessons/style.css' %}" />
<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "20%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "20%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "20%";
}
</script>


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="active">Home</a>

<a href = "{% url 'lessons:index' %}"class="active">Lessons</a>

<a href="{% url 'resources' %}"class="active">Resources</a>

</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:crosshair;display:inline-block" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

<h1>Exercise</h1>
<form id = "exercise" action= " ">
{% for question in lesson.question_set.all %}
{% autoescape off %}{{ question.question_text }} {% endautoescape %}<BR>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
  {% if choice.answer %}
<input type="radio" name="question{{question.pk}}" value=1 />{% autoescape off %}{{ choice.choice_text }}{% endautoescape %}<BR>
  {% else %}
<input type="radio" name="question{{question.pk}}" value=0 />{% autoescape off %}{{ choice.choice_text }}{% endautoescape %}<BR>
  {% endif %}
<!--<label for="{{question.pk}}choice{{ forloop.counter }}"></label><br />-->

{% endfor %}
<BR>
{% endfor %}<BR><BR>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><BR><BR>
</form>
</div>

<center><p id="grade">Your grade is: </p></center>

<button class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
  {% for question in lesson.question_set.all %}
  {% autoescape off %}{{question.answer}} {% endautoescape %}
  {% endfor %}
<BR><BR>
  <p align=center><a href="/../lessons/{{lesson.lesson_id}}" class="backbutton"><span><font-size=14px>Return to Lesson</font></span></a>
    <a href="/../lessons/quiz/{{lesson.lesson_id}}" class="button"><span><font-size=14px>Quiz {{lesson.lesson_id}}</font></span></a><BR><BR>
</div>

<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
```

Javascript functions

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>

//start function
    <script>
  document.getElementById("exercise").onsubmit = function() {
  var result=0;
  { % for question in lesson.question_set.all % }
  result += parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "question{{question.pk}}"]:checked').value);
  { % endfor % }
  document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
  return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
  } //this ends the submit function
</script>
//end function






  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

So I am using Django to create a website and I am having trouble figuring out why " document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result; " does not change " Your grade is:

" I have moved the p tag all over the page and still cannot get innerHTML to change whats in the tag. I have also changed result to different values and it still doesn't change the p tag. I also placed all the javascript functions in the same script as well. I want the page to submit the quiz and show the results. What am I doing wrong? Later, I want to show which questions are incorrect and what are the correct answers. 
I'd appreciate the help. Thank you!

Here is the corrected script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
var result=0;
var count=0;
{% for question in lesson.question_set.all %}
result += parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "question{{question.pk}}"]:checked').value);
count++;
{% endfor %}
document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = "You got a "+result+"/"+count+". If you would like to retake the quiz please resubmit!";
return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
} //this ends the submit function
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `getElementById` not `getElementsById`.

`document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;`

Comment: @nvurdien it should work, learn to look at your developer's console and find any errors. update your post with that if you can't fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay was at a hackathon. Here are the images: http://imgur.com/a/vmtNz

Comment: @nvurdien wrong variable, you're using `result` but on the `innerHTML` you're passing the `results` variable which is undefined

Comment: I changed it. It refreshes the page whenever I try to submit the answer. I tried using AJAX but I am unsure how to do it that way and it refreshes the page that way too. I updated the code above

Comment: @nvurdien based from your code you're not doing it via ajax, you're doing it onsubmit, which will absolutely going to refresh your page. Ajax is more like preventing the submit behavior and pulling the elements value and generate request to the server and process the returned data

Comment: Yeah I changed it back to the way it is now because it still wasn't working out

Comment: @nvurdien lets talk here hurry http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141391/chatchatchat